# I want to align my buttons at the end in a paper-dialog

Tags: html, css, polymer

I have a `paper-dialog` with a fixed size and I want to align a `<div>` containing a button at the end. The `paper-dialog` contains a `header`, `paper-tabs` that controls the `iron-pages` below. The `iron-pages` contain the button.

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-dialog {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 585px;
    }
</style>

<paper-dialog>
    <header>Header</header>
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}>
        <paper-tab> tab1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab> tab2</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
        <div id="tab1" container class="container layout vertical">
            <div> Text section tab1</div>
            <div class="flex></div>
            <div>
                <paper-button id="toBeAlignedAtTheBottom">next!</paper-button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" container class="container layout vertical">
            <div> Text section tab2</div>
            <div class="flex></div>
            <div>
                <paper-button id="toBeAlignedAtTheBottom">next!</paper-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </iron-pages>
</paper-dialog>
```

But I can never get the buttons to be aligned at the end of the `paper-dialog`. Only by using a fixed size for the container classes inside the `iron-pages`. The length of the text section in `tab1` and `tab2` differ greatly. That is why I want to modify how the buttons are aligned and are positioned at the button. How can I do this without using a fixed size?

Comment: can you share some link of the dialog where you are using it? I mean some live link to your code where I can see what is happening?

Comment: Try to add to your parent button element a class `div class=buttons`. Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue. The problem was that every parent class of the buttons have to use all the remaining space. So add `flex` to every parent class. Secondly add `end` to position the buttons on the bottom.

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-dialog {
                width: 1000px;
                height: 585px;
    }
</style>

<paper-dialog class="flex layout vertical">
    <header>Header</header>
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}>
        <paper-tab> tab1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab> tab2</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <iron-pages class="flex layout vertical" selected="{{selected}}">
        <div id="tab1" container class="container flex layout vertical">
            <div> Text section tab1</div>
            <div class="flex></div>
            <div class="layout horizontal end">
                <paper-button id="toBeAlignedAtTheBottom">next!</paper-button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" container class="container layout vertical">
            <div> Text section tab2</div>
            <div class="flex></div>
            <div>
                <paper-button id="toBeAlignedAtTheBottom">next!</paper-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </iron-pages>
</paper-dialog>
```

See also: [Fill page with iron-pages element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598105/fill-page-with-iron-pages-element)